# What is Ahalyā's birth name?

Tags: ramayana, sanskrit, name, etymology, ahalya

Is 'Ahalyā' the real name of Gautama's wife or is it an acquired name?

At least, the [Monier-Williams dictionary](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/monier/serveimg.pl?file=/scans/MWScan/MWScanjpg/mw0125-ahalyA.jpg) seems to think it's an acquired one. The word is listed as *a* + *halyā*:

> अ-हल्या (A-halyā)  f. N. of the wife of गौतम or शरद्वत्   S3Br. iii , &c   MBh. &c

One of the meanings of *[halya](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=halya&direct=se)* (not *halyā*) is 'deformity' so *ahalyā* probably means 'no longer a deformed person'. If this is the correct etymology of the word, what is Ahalyā's (w/o Gautama) real or birth name?

Answer (score 4):

**Is 'Ahalyā' the real name of Gautama's wife or is it an acquired name?**

Yes, this is her birth/real name which was given by Lord Brahma. This is given in [this chapter of UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-35):

> [Lord Brahma to Indra]: O Chief of the immortals! O lord !, some
>   creatures were created by me by dint of my understanding they were all
>   of the same colour, same speech, and same appearance. There was no
>   diference visible in their appearance or marks.
>
> Thereupon, with whole minded ness, I began to think of these created
>   beings. And I created a female distinct from them.
>
> Collecting all those limbs that were most excellent amongst the
>   created, I made a female under the name of Ahalya.
>
> **Hal means ugliness one born from Hal is called Halya. That female was known as Ahalya because she had nothing blameable in her. I gave
>   her that name.**

Here are the screenshots of Sanskrit Shlokas:

> [image] 
>   [image]

Comment: Ok. But is it  a + halya OR a + halyā? How does a + halya become ahalyā?

Comment: @sv. It is ahalyā originally but the translation in the answer used simplified version rather than exact transliteration. Many use simplified transliteration. I think ahalyā was derived due to Nay Tatpurusha Samas.  na + halyā = ahalya.

Comment: Also, "Ahalya because she had nothing blameable in her" - - this suggests it's an acquired name. How can you name someone not-blameable when she did something blameworthy? If you remove all the mythology surrounding Ahalya, it becomes apparent it's an acquired name due to Rama's visit purifying her.

Comment: @sv. Here blameable is used for ugliness and not for it's exact meaning...if u read Sanskrit Shloka or Hindi translation it will be clear to you..